# How to add another user to this remove_menu function?

Tags: functions, user-roles, user-access

Pretty self-explanatory. How does one add another user to this function for functions.php, i.e., user2, who will be shown different menu items than user1?

I tried adding another `if($current_user->user_login == 'user2')` condition, but no luck. User2 will have different admin rights, if that matters. But basically, I need to be able to show one set of menu items to user1 and another set to user2, so I need to figure out some if else logic. But I tried that, and I get a "can't redeclare a previously declared" error for the menu function.

```
  function remove_menus()
{
    global $menu;
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if($current_user->user_login == 'user1')
    {
        $restricted = array(
                            __('Links'),
                            __('Comments'),
                            __('Appearance'),
                            __('Plugins'),
                            __('Profile'),
                            __('Tools'),
                            __('Settings')
        );
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }
        }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

Comment: How about using current_user_can and check by role name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add another if?

```
function remove_menus(){
    global $menu;
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
   //check first user
    if($current_user->user_login == 'user1'){
        $restricted = array(
                            __('Links'),
                            __('Comments'),
                            __('Appearance'),
                            __('Plugins'),
                            __('Profile'),
                            __('Tools'),
                            __('Settings')
        );
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }
    }
    //check second user
    if($current_user->user_login == 'user2'){
        $restricted = array(
                            __('Links'),
                            __('Comments'),
                            __('Appearance'),
                            __('Plugins')
        );
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }
    }

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

same function but two different users will get different menus.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was trying to do, but I had the logic wrong. This works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not simply add an `or` into your conditional logic?

```
if( $current_user->user_login == 'user1' || $current_user->user_login == 'user2' )
```

Or even better just use an array, so it's easier to update..

Before the `if` line mentioned above..

```
$_menu_remove_users = array( 'user1', 'user2' );
```

Then replace the existing if condition with..

```
if( in_array( $current_user->user_login, $_menu_remove_users ) )
```

You can then update the array as needed without needing to rewrite your conditional logic.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to show one set of menu items to one user and a different set to a second user, so I need "if else" logic, but I get a "can't redeclare a previously declared" error for the menu code. So I don't know how it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's - [a small plugin i wrote](https://gist.github.com/942518) - that works & is tested.

You can simply upload it and test it using the following function inside your `functions.php` file:

#### How to

```
# Add a user to a user group from inside your functions.php file
function test_me( $user_group_A )
{
    $user_group_A[] = 'Take your own name for testing';

    return $user_group_A;
}
add_filter( 'user_group_A', 'test_me' );
```

#### Notes

Adding one (or more) users to one of the groups is as easy as shown above. Modifying the menu item groups is nearly the same. Just handle those arrays inside your themes functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice little plugin. Appreciate your effort, but I want to keep it simple and assign those roles just in functions.php

Comment: Ok. You could also simply add the function to your functions.php file and add the `test_me()`-function after it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your trying to hide certain menu items for certain users, you can do this by making use [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) instead of hard coding usernames and removing menu items. The [Capsman](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/) plugin allows you to flexible set permissions for admin, editor roles and even define new ones. If a user does not have permissions to see the Settings page, then the admin links will be removed by WordPress.

Comment: I want to keep simple role assigments in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the Plugin [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/), with this plugin you can easy hide menus for different roles; also custom roles. maybe its easier as custom code, if you like this.